# SSIS Fails to set destination path variable in File System Task

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, ide, sql-server-data-tools

I have some very sad UI problem. In one of my SSIS packeges at certain point of time I'm using simple "File Sitem Task" to rename file. The name of the file I'm forming via some complex logic on previous steps and this name settles in variable.

So, the problem is when I'm trying to set destination connection based on variable GUI fails on variable selection. I attached .gif file to illustrate the issue.

These issue reproduces both in Visual Studio 2015 community and SQL Server Data Tools IDE's. I'm using win7 x64 with latest updates. Any advice on this problem?
[image]

Comment: What is the scope of the variable? Is it applied to all or just part of the package?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't matter. There should be a dropdown menu with list of available variables and onption to create a new one, but it fails instead of showing this list. In my gif example there are no any variables in package, but it still fails.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't solve the UI issue, but have found the way to edit this field in raw text of package...
[image: raw package text]